# Typing indicator shows even afterr message is sent Bot Framework Composer

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat, bot-framework-composer

Exactly what the title says. I've been trying to implement the typing indicator (befor bot sends a message) for a bot created through Bot Framework Composer. The guidelines are to set the the `showTyping` property in `appsettings.json` to true but when I do this it will sometimes displays the typing indicator before the bot sends a message but sometimes it will display the typing indicator after the bot message.

I've already looked up this error and there doesn't seem to be support on it anywhere for Bot Framework Composer but there are resources for this same issue occurring using Bot Framework SDK. I have extensively read and tried all the suggestions for the SDK version but can't seem to get it to work. I don't know if I'm missing some code that hooks the components together but I've done a number of things which generally include

- Creating a `CustomShowTypingMiddleware.cs`
- Create and edit the `AdapterWithErrorHandler.cs`
- Use the adapter in `Startup.cs`

I don't know if something else is meant to be added to any of the other composer c# files (ex. `BotController.cs`, `Program.cs`) but these were the changes I noticed in the code samples so this is all I added. By making these changes, it seems to do nothing. It doesn't break the bot but it doesn't add any typing functionality either. An alternative I've tried that was working only locally was creating a custom middleware component (following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-create-custom-actions?tabs=csharp#export-the-bot-runtime), referencing it inside my composer bot and then adding the name of the new component to my `components` array in `appsettings.json`. This successfully sent the typing activity and showed it in chat locally but whenever I would deploy the code to Azure and Test in Webchat or use it in our client application linked to this hosted Azure bot, it would always send back a 502/500 error saying that there's a missing secret or token on the request `webchat/join` when in fact the Authorization header shows otherwise.

I would appreciate any help on trying to make either methods (adapter or custom component) work or a new one if there is anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out the problem with my custom bot component implementation was that it was an external project.

I think because the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-create-custom-actions?tabs=csharp#export-the-bot-runtime) are a littled dated. They reference a `.sln` file that as far as I know does not exist anymore in the template Composer projects. Because of this, I created a blank solution in VS where I opened my existing bot project and created a new project for the component. I mainly followed the instructions [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfQ9zm7K0HI&ab_channel=LearnMicrosoftAI) which are very similar to the docs (just specifically for components instead of actions) but at the end I moved the component project into the bot project directory. Then I adjusted the project reference in the `<bot>.csproj` to point to the newly moved component project. Added some `<Generate...Attribute>false</Generate...Attribute>` attributes in `<PropertyGroup>` of the `<component>.csproj` (again now in the bot project instead of outside of it) to remove the duplicate attribute errors I was getting. Deleted the `bin/` and `obj/` directories of both the bot project and the component project. Then it worked fine both locally and on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

@owenpww

Setting `"showTyping":"true"` is all that is needed to enable the typing middleware, as you have found.

There are a few aspects to the how the typing middleware works. There is the delay on how long the request has to continue before any typing activity is sent. Think of this as the threshold that is wanted, to allow the bot to reply before *any* typing activity is sent. The default is 500ms. The second aspect is how often/frequent typing activities are sent before the response is sent and typing activities are cancelled. The default is every 2 seconds. You can see this [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/a216a9b469b3ed18c8a6f6b5e47c627b70b0830b/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ShowTypingMiddleware.cs#L31). The third aspect is how long the client wants to render their typing activity. The [spec recommends displaying for 3 seconds](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/blob/main/specs/botframework-activity/botframework-activity.md#typing-activity). Looks like webchat is at least close to that. The spec also says that the clients can clear the activity if it is assigned an id.

So, the question I have is; what are you seeing in WebChat/Emulator (does it even behave the same in Emulator?) with regards to the order of typing activities coming in and relation to the message activity. Do you see multiple typing activities? Do you they show in the correct order in the trace, but in the wrong order in the chat (what the user sees)? If you are able to massage your bot to take longer/shorter responses (no longer than 15 seconds), how does that affect the behavior?

Here's what you would look for in Emulator or Composer Webchat:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Dana V, thank you for your response. I'm aware of these things but unsure how to act on them since I'm using Composer and not the SDK. When I use the emulator/Composer to test, the logs always show up in this order user input -> typing -> bot response although I do not notice anything on the UI because the bot seems to run faster on local. However, when I publish the code to my Azure Bot, there's no way for me to see the order of events aside from what I see on the UI which as I mentioned is sometimes user input > typing > bot message but other times user input > bot message > typing

Comment: "If you are able to massage your bot to take longer/shorter responses (no longer than 15 seconds), how does that affect the behavior?" what does massaging my bot mean or do you mean message my bot? In either case, I don't think I understand what you mean.

Comment: Hello @dana-v not sure if I tagged you correctly